# PhP fread and stripos

Tags: php, fread, stripos

I´m getting data with

```
$newtext = fread($rcon, 102400);
```

But this script is not working. I tried it with different things burning thing the text I get from my rcon function is not a normal text... Does it make sense ?

```
$offset = stripos($newtext, 'ÿ');
```

But if i print it i could see the y

```
EYî ÿ5aa68
```

Why is it not working? Its kind of wired.. Because .. It is there..^^ I'm sorry if there is an obvious mistake. I'm pretty new to these things.

Thanks for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [mb_stripos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-stripos.php) function.
It designed to work with multibyte strings in php.

```
arth@arth:~$ php -r 'echo stripos("EYî ÿ5aa68", "ÿ")."\n";'                                                                                                                    
5
arth@arth:~$ php -r 'echo mb_stripos("EYî ÿ5aa68", "ÿ")."\n";'
5
```

Comment: `0` or `false`? `0` means `found at 0 position`

Comment: var_dump($newtext) gives me : `string(486) "BEÆ2Èÿb52118f75da73b948a(OK) [and so on]"` so its a string.. i dont get it..